# Mimic iOS 13 fullscreen dialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I noticed that in iOS 13 full screen dialog has changed, introducing a new slide from bottom animation.
Here is an example

[image]

Is it possible to mimic this behaviour with flutter? iOS animation it's not a simple slide from bottom but involves also the background page.

Looking throught flutter documentation I found [this class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition-class.html) but, without any example I can't understand how to use it or if it's what I'm searching.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530136/how-to-use-cupertinofullscreendialogtransition ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**: Based on another answer by @VadimKo, I now understand that the stacking effect might also be desired. The answer linked to a package [modal_bottom_sheet](https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet) based on which I have updated my example

If I'm understanding your question right, you want to show a full screen dialog that slides up from the bottom and has UI similar to the one showed in your picture.

`CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition` is really just two `SlideTransition`s stacked up so it's nothing special.

You could achieve something close to the posted images by using `showGeneralDialog`

In that, you could show anything using the combination of `pageBuilder` and `transitionBuilder`. It's very flexible and can even be used to show full routes on top of current route.

If you use `CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition` as the `pageBuilder` it should achieve your goal. It's not required to provide a `transitionBuilder` since it's being performed by the `pageBuilder` implicitly.

The following example tries to mimic requested UI by using `CupertinoApp`, `CustomScrollView` and `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar` for the content of the dialog

**Update**: A `transitionBuilder` similar to the one provided by [modal_bottom_sheet](https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet) can be used to add the stacking effect.

Important code from the DartPad example:

```dart
showGeneralDialog(
  barrierDismissible: true,
  barrierLabel: 'Settings',
  barrierColor: Colors.black,
  context: context,
  /// This would be slow but good to understand how transitions are working
  transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
  /// Optionally provide the [transitionBuilder] to get the stacking effect 
  /// as of iOS 13
  transitionBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
    /// The following transition widget was inspired from `modal_bottom_sheet` package
    /// Some modifications have been made to remove certain limitations,
    /// See the full DartPad example or take a look at `modal_bottom_sheet`
    return _CupertinoModalTransition(
      animation: animation,
      child: child,
      /// This renders the current widget behind the modal
      /// Notice the use of [this], it is to make sure correct context is used
      behindChild: this.build(this.context),
    );
  },
  pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
    /// This is the simplest use case for [CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition]
    /// This provides the slide up and slide down transition effects
    return CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition(
      primaryRouteAnimation: animation,
      secondaryRouteAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
      /// Content of your dialog
      child: Container(),
      linearTransition: true,
    );
  },
);
```

DartPad Full example : https://dartpad.dev/57de88ce8d64dff9d3e6fe0627a8b654

**Update**: The DartPad example works just like `modal_bottom_sheet` but *without any need to make changes to existing code* such as the requirement to use `MaterialWithModalsPageRoute` or to wrap current/preview routes in `CupertinoScaffold` both of which are provided by the same package.

Preview:

[image: Preview]

See the GIF preview: https://i.imgur.com/mZ77M62.gifv

Note: There is already `showCupertinoDialog` provided by the flutter team but it doesn't provide as much flexibility. It can however be used for normal small dialog popups that don't usually take full screen space.

Answer (score 2):

You can always build your own widgets, however in this case you can use an existing package: [Modal bottom sheet](https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet)

you can also check some more existing flutter issues here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35026)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package [cupertino_fullscreen_modal](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_fullscreen_modal)

```
CupertinoFullscreenModal.of(context).showModal(Widget child, onClose (popValue) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try another already existing package [Cupertino Stackview](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_stackview)

```
CupertinoStackView(
  true,             //_isPrimary 
  "Page I",         //_navigation
  Scaffold(...),    //_child
  Colors.black,     //_backgroundColor 
 {Key key,
  isDismissible : true,
  radius        : Radius.circular(10.0)})
```