# How do you configure this kind of screen transition in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile

I am creating my app using Flutter.
However, I'm encountering difficulties with a particular implementation.

I would like to create a page that floats up from the bottom when a specific button is pressed, similar to the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mscRy.gif)

I've been trying various approaches, but it seems different from using showBottomSheet or showModalBottomSheet. What should I attempt to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, it's a liitle bit difficult for you to create your own page transition animation which animate both incoming page and the outcoming page like in your example img, you can check [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419056/how-to-animate-old-page-during-transition-in-flutter) to learn about the workaround.

If you are not cared about the animation of the old page, maybe you can use a custom page transition to implement the similar page route animation, below is the example code in the flutter official doc

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
    ),
  );
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
          },
          child: const Text('Go!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const Page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Notice that in the case above you use the `transitionBuilder` to customize the page switch animation

by the way flutter did provide an iOS style UI package `cupertino` which has a `CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition` widget. You can check [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530136/how-to-use-cupertinofullscreendialogtransition) to check out how to use `CupertinoFullscreenDialogTransition` and here is the [offical doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/widgets/cupertino) of `cupertino`

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: StreamBuilder<double>(
            stream: paddingController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              padding = snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data! : 0;
              return AnimatedPadding(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: padding, top: padding, right: padding),
                child: DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(padding == 0 ? 0 : 10),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(padding == 0 ? 0 : 10)),
                  ),
                  child: const SizedBox(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Content...'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
        bottomNavigationBar: ColoredBox(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: showDlg,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
              ),
              const Icon(Icons.card_travel),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showDlg() {
    paddingController.sink.add(30);
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
      )),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 800),
      builder: (context) => const SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Dialog Content'),
        ),
      ),
    ).then((value) {
      paddingController.sink.add(0);
    });
  }
```