# Reproducing an IOS animation with Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, user-interface, animation, mobile

There's a type of animation that we can find in many features on IOS devices, but I couldn't figure out any information about that, probably because I even don't know how it is called. One of those places that it appears is when I am adding a new contact. The animation stacks the new screen over the previous one, like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb9pk.gif).

Is there a specific name I can search information about that animation? Is there some library that can help reproduce this on Flutter?

Comment: This answerws a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967557/mimic-ios-13-fullscreen-dialog

Answer (score -1):

It's called a bottom sheet.
Using Flutter you can call this bottom sheet using [`showBottomSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html).
Like so:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    child: const Text('showBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>(
            (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: // More widgets ...
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```